# How to set Environment for asp.net 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am currently working on a asp.net 4.6.1 project.
I have used bundler and minifier extension to minify and it works as desired to minify files. I wanted to minify all the js and css files and set the reference links according to the environment.

This is not possible in ASP.NET 4.6.1
My main aim is that normal files should load during debug mode and minified files during production mode.

Something of this type :

```
<environment names="Development"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file1.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file2.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file3.css" /> 
</environment> 
<environment names="Staging,Production"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundle1.min.css" asp-append-version="true" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundle2.min.css" asp-append-version="true" /> 
</environment>
```

Comment: Something of this type:-
`<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/file3.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundle1.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundle2.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>`

Comment: Add from comment :)